# Creating multiple divs in jQuery zIndex

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to make a function which runs on the $(document).ready() event and it supouse to create a new div. Now when I want to make another div, with same DOM and Class attributes but on different possition, here is the problem...

```js
 
 //Updating z-index in css duo to more than 1 note
 var zIndex = 10000;
 function updateIndex(element){
  zIndex = zIndex+1; //Counter, '++' = +1
  $(element).css('z-index', zIndex);
  }
  
  
 $("div .makeNew").on("click", function(e) {
  updateIndex(this);
 });
 $(".note input textarea").on("click", function(e) {
  updateIndex(this);
 });


 
 function MakeNewNote(){
  zIndex = zIndex + 1;
  $('#content').css('z-index', zIndex).append("<div class="note" ><div id="controlsTop"><div class="deleteNote">X</div><div class="makeNew">+</div></div><input value="My Note" /><textarea value="I Have something to save" cols="20" name="S1" rows="1"></textarea><div id="controlsExtra hidden"><div class="controlBold"></div><div class="controlItalic"></div><div class="controlUnderlined"></div><div class="controlLeft"></div><div class="controlCenter"></div><div class="controlRight"></div><div class="controlBigFont"></div><div class="controlSmallFont"></div></div> <!-- controlsExtra --></div> <!-- note -->");
  $('.note').draggable();
 }
 
 function DeleteThisNote(){
  $('.note').remove();
 }
 
 $(document).ready(MakeNewNote); // Creates a note just at startup
 
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('div .makeNew').on('click', MakeNewNote); // Creates a new note, enables button press inside the note 
  
  $('div .deleteNote').one('click', DeleteThisNote); // Removes current note
  
 });
```

```css
/* CSS DOCUMENT */
/* Autor: Ismar Hadzic */
/* Description: Main style for Sticky Notes */
/* Licensed to WiKey inc. All rights reserverd 2015 */

.note {
 width: 200px; height: 200px;
 background:#FFFFCC;
 margin:15px;
 
 
}

.note .controlsTop {
 background:#FFFF66;
 padding-top:50px;
 margin-left:10px;
}

.note .controlsTop .deleteNote {
 width:10px;
 display:block;
 float:left;
 margin-left:5px;
 
}

.note .controlsTop .makeNew {
 width:10px;
 display:block;
 float:left;
 margin-left:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  // Should output here
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two changes that should fix your issue:

Firstly, onnly initialize the `div.note` just added ... not all the existing ones:
Change `$('.note').draggable();` to:

```
$('.note').last().draggable();
```

Secondly, delete the appropriate `div.note`:
Change `$('.note').remove();` to:

```
$(this).closest('.note').remove();
```

**Update**

Elements that are created after *DOM ready* event need *delegated events* for them to work:

```
$('#content').on('click', 'div .makeNew', MakeNewNote);

$('#content').one('click', 'div .deleteNote', DeleteThisNote);
```

Comment: Yes this solved deleting the div after a click, but buttons on other divs do not work...

$('div .note .makeNew').on('click', MakeNewNote);

How do I make it to work on all created divs?

Comment: On the latest update, it does not work at all :( I'll close this topic because there is an stickynotes.js plugin which has all needed functions.